# Terraform - For_each - You have provided a value of type list of object

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I get the following error when try out for_each (which is a type of list of objects) but the same thing works fine in a  dynamic block.

Here is the error:

`The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type list of object.`

This is the module where I get the error

```
      vpc_subnets = [
        {name: "public_test_a", cidr_block: "10.0.0.0/28", map_public_ip_on_launch: true,  availability_zone: "ap-south-1a"},
        {name: "public_test_b", cidr_block: "10.0.0.16/28", map_public_ip_on_launch: true,  availability_zone: "ap-south-1b"},
        {name: "private_test_a", cidr_block: "10.0.0.32/28", map_public_ip_on_launch: false,  availability_zone: "ap-south-1a"},
        {name: "private_test_b", cidr_block: "10.0.0.48/28", map_public_ip_on_launch: false,  availability_zone: "ap-south-1b"}
      ]

# Create Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
    for_each = var.vpc_subnets

    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    cidr_block = each.value.cidr_block
    map_public_ip_on_launch = each.value.map_public_ip_on_launch
    availability_zone = each.value.availability

    tags = merge({
      Name = each.value.name
    }, var.subnet_tags)
}
```

But in another module, it works fine. The only difference is that its in a dynamic block.

```
  ingress_rules = [
    {description: "Port 3306", cidr_blocks: ["10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.4.0/24"], port: 3306, protocol: "tcp"},
    {description: "Port 22",   cidr_blocks: ["0.0.0.0/0"], port: 22, protocol: "tcp"},
    {description: "port 80",   cidr_blocks: ["0.0.0.0/0"], port: 80, protocol: "tcp"}
  ]

resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
  name = var.name

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.ingress_rules

    content {
      description = ingress.value.description
      cidr_blocks = ingress.value.cidr_blocks
      from_port   = ingress.value.port
      to_port     = ingress.value.port
      protocol    = ingress.value.protocol
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work, because [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings), when used to create resources, accepts only **a map or a set of strings** and you are passing a list of maps.

Thus, you have to modify it to use a map only:

```
# Create Subnets
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {

    for_each = {for idx, subnet in var.vpc_subnets: idx => subnet}

    vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
    cidr_block = each.value.cidr_block
    map_public_ip_on_launch = each.value.map_public_ip_on_launch
    availability_zone = each.value.availability

    tags = merge({
      Name = each.value.name
    }, var.subnet_tags)
}
```

[for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) used in dynamic blocks does not have such limitations, so you can iterate over your list of maps.

Comment: cool thanks. Can you answer this as well? I've been trying a different approach. But I'll try this method as well.  Here is the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853110/terraform-create-type-constraints-for-type-map