# Terraform - Create type constraints for type Map

Tags: terraform, type-constraints

What would be the correct way to create type constraints for type map?

This doesn't seem valid.

```
variable "vpc_subnets" {
  type = map(
    key = {name  = string, cidr_block = string, map_public_ip_on_launch = bool, availability_zone = string}
  )
}
```

Here is what the map looks like..

```
  vpc_subnets = {
    "public_subnet_a" = {name = "public_test_a", cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/28", map_public_ip_on_launch = true,  availability_zone = "ap-south-1a"},
    "public_subnet_b" = {name = "public_test_b", cidr_block = "10.0.0.16/28", map_public_ip_on_launch = true,  availability_zone = "ap-south-1b"},
    "private_subnet_a" = {name = "private_test_a", cidr_block = "10.0.0.32/28", map_public_ip_on_launch = false,  availability_zone = "ap-south-1a"},
    "private_subnet_b" ={name = "private_test_b", cidr_block = "10.0.0.48/28", map_public_ip_on_launch = false,  availability_zone = "ap-south-1b"}
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `vpc_subnets` is map of objects, so you could use:

```
variable "vpc_subnets" {
  type = map(
    object({name  = string, cidr_block = string, map_public_ip_on_launch = bool, availability_zone = string})
  )
```